# how to just print the statement without any loop condition in java?

Tags: loops

I just want to print the "hello" 5 times without using for loop,while loop ?

Comment: print "hello"; print "hello"; print "hello"; print "hello";

Comment: @BlackBear: I don't think that approach will work.  It only printed 4 times when I ran it.

Comment: @recursive: improving the algorithm is an exercise for the reader =P

Comment: what about perl's "until" construct? </sarcasm>

Comment: Or python `str = 'bob'` 
`print bob * 5` :)

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println("hello hello hello hello hello");
```

Comment: That prints "hello" 5 times and a space 4 times :)

Comment: @khachik: space was added for clarity ;-)

Comment: sorry i got it.using recursive function also we can print...           static void rec(int n) {
  if(n == 0)
   return;
  System.out.println(" hello");
  rec(n-1);
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with recursion. Is this homework? Sounds like it, so I'll not give a full answer unless you say otherwise.

Comment: i agree but that's not an answer, sounds more like a comment

Comment: I feel this is an answer, and that it points the OP in the right direction. Which is more than the other sarcastic answers do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String repeat(String str, int times){
   return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
}
//...
String bob = "bob ";
System.out.println(repeat(bob, 5));
```